# Moment generating function of sample mean of bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p \in (0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We consider a sample of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with parameter p.

Computer $E[e^{\lambda\bar{X_n}}]$ such that $\bar{X_n}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

$E[e^{\lambda\bar{X_n}}]=E[e^{\frac{\lambda}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}]=e^{\frac{1}{n}}E[e^{\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}]= e^{\frac{1}{n}}E[e^{\lambda X_1}]\dots E[e^{\lambda X_n}]=e^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-p+pe^{\lambda})^n$

Is it correct ?

Comment: In the second $=$ you should not have taken $e^{1/n}$ "outside."

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have used the fact that $E[\lambda X]= \lambda E[X]$. Is it incorrect ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So why is taking out the $e^{\frac{1}{n}}$ incorrect ? I did that in order to get the moment generating function of all the random variables

Comment: @user43418 $e^{\lambda/n} \neq e^{\lambda}e^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use $t$ as the variable instead of $\lambda$. The required  expectation is 
$$\left(E(\exp(\frac{tX_1}{n})\right)^n,$$
and
$$E(\exp(\frac{tX_1}{n}))=(1-p)+pe^{\frac{t}{n}}.$$

Comment: I understand. Thank you for taking the time and writing an answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Small algebra slip.  One could also use the general expression for the mgf of $kY$ in terms of the mgf of $Y$. But since you had started on a direct computation, I thought I might as well use most of it.

Comment: Hence the final solution is given by: $((1-p)+pe^{\frac{\lambda}{n}})^n$

Comment: Yes, that's right.